# How do I redirect to another page in a condition using php?

Tags: php, html

I want to redirect to `index.html?id=div2` when the if condition is statisfied. And if not, then it should reload the page.

How do I do that?

```
if($checkAll > 0){
    // Redirect to index.html?id=div2  
} else{
    //Reload page
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: @can you explain me your code little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use headers:

```
if($checkAll > 0){
    header("Location: /index.html?id=div2"); 
} else{
    header("Refresh:0");
}
// die();
```

Answer (score 0):

/* Redirect browser */

> header("Location: yourUrl.com");
> exit();

it's a good practice to call exit() right after it so that code below it does not get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I use redirect like this.

```
function redirect_to($location) {
    header("Location: " . $location);
    exit;
}


if($checkAll > 0) {
    $new_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
    redirect_to('/index.php?id=' . $new_id);
      } else {
    redirect_to('/index.php');
}
```